# in django model foreign key not retrieving actual value

Tags: python, django

in django i defined two tables 1. country 2.state
while i am trying to print country_id from State table its retriving like "State object (1)" i am expectin number alone like 1 ,2 3

```
    # location lookup 
class Country(models.Model):
    country_id=models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
    country_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country_code=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

# state lookup 
class State(models.Model):
    state_id=models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
    state_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country_id=models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='country_id')
```

Comment: try `<State_object>.country_id.country_id`

Comment: `state_instance.country_id` would give you an instance of `Country` (don't name foreign keys as `field_id` as then you would have an automatically generated field `field_id_id`) so either `state_instance.country_id_id` or `state_instance.country_id.country_id` will give you what you want.

Comment: country_id.country_id is working but. i want to use directly use country_id from state table.

Comment: @AsaimaniAsaithambi check my comment above....

Comment: class State(models.Model):
    state_id=models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
    state_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country=models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='country')  
shall put country insted of country_id so that i can access state.country_id for actual vaue.

Answer (score 0):

even I had done the same mistake for the first time.

You are probably trying

**State.country_id**

and printing that. Instead you have to do

**State.country_id.country_id**

When you simply use the first option the output is the object State itself and not the country_id so you have to say the value of country_id inside the object country_id that’s why you have to use a dot there.

So what most of us do is inside of the class **State** we will call the field name as **country** instead of **country_id** as we can they state “Get me the id of the instance country” by using

**State.country.country_id**

Comment: thanks country_id.country_id is working but. i want to use directly use country_id from state table. so for what i need to do for model.

Comment: For that you just have to create another field in the State with the country_id value just like you have done for the Country, otherwise if you want to link the country to the state as well as not want to use country_id twice it will not be possible.

Comment: You can use **State.country_id_id**

Comment: ass State(models.Model): state_id=models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True) state_name=models.CharField(max_length=50) country=models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='country') shall put country insted of country_id so that i can access state.country_id for actual vaue.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped, thanks